# how to delete an object from join model object in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Event model:

```
 has_many :users, through: :event_users
 has_many :event_users
```

a User model:

```
 has_many :events, through: :event_users
 has_many :event_users
```

and an EventUser model:

```
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :user
```

On my event page, I have a list of Event users:

```
<% @event.users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
    <li>        
        <%= user.try(:display_name) %>
            <%= link_to "delete",  user, method: :delete, class: 'btn', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

When I click the "delete" link, the User object is deleted, instead of the EventUser. I don't have any idea what the syntax should be in the link_to in order to reference the correct object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to "delete",  user, method: :delete` goes to UsersController#delete. You need separate action (or maybe controller) to delete EventUsers. Something like:

```
EventsController
  def remove_user
    event = Event.find(params[:id])
    event_user = event.event_users.find_by!(user_id: params[:user_id])
    event_user.destroy
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :events do
  delete remove_user, on: :member, as: :remove_user
end
```

form:

```
<% @event.users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <li>        
    <%= user.try(:display_name) %>
    <%= link_to "delete",  remove_user_path(@event, user_id: user.id), method: :delete, class: 'btn', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @phauwn, happy to help :)